# How to join 2 table with xml coulmns in sql server?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to join 2 tables with XML Column in simplest way. I did this with XML, String but I'm trying to find a better way.

Tables are designed like:

```
PhoneNoTable:  PhoneNo(varchar), ImportState(xml or string)

ImportStateTable : ID (int) , Title(varchar)
```

In table PhoneNoTable field ImportState is associated  to  ID Field in  ImportStateTable.

For example:

```
PhoneNoTable :  PhoneNo    ImportState
                 123         <1,2,3>
                 222         <1>


ImportStateTable:  ID       Title
                   1        'X'
                   2        'Y'
                   3        'z'
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I need t-sql that return the  PhoneNo that ImportState fields are equal to <1,2>